# Yahoo/OAuth Could Not Get Access Token

Tags: php, api, oauth, yahoo

I am trying to implement OAuth on my site using php. I don't have access to the server so I can't install a OAuth library. Instead I have the following code provided to me by yahoo, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Here's there error I keep getting:

```
Hey! Go to this URL and tell us the verifier you get at the end. https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=bhppbwq Type the verifier and hit enter... Here's the verifier you gave us: Could not get access token
```

It looks like it's trying to give some type of interaction, but It doesn't give me a chance. Instead it goes straight to a blank page and spits that error out.

Here is the yahoo code I was given:

```
 <?php  
// **** POTENTIAL CONFIGURATION STARTS HERE ****  

// MODIFY: Insert your own consumer key and secret here!  
$consumer_data = array();  
$consumer_data['test']['key']    = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';  
$consumer_data['test']['secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';  


// **** HELPER FUNCTIONS START HERE ****  

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
//  FUNCTION _make_signed_request  
/// @brief Helper function to make a signed OAuth request. Only allows GET   
///        requests at the moment. Will add on standard OAuth params, but  
///        you may need to fill in non-generic ones ahead of time.  
///  
/// @param[in]  $consumer_key      Application consumer key  
/// @param[in]  $consumer_secret   Application consumer secret  
/// @param[in]  $token             Token (request or access token)  
/// @param[in]  $token_secret      Token secret  
/// @param[in]  $signature_method  'PLAINTEXT' or 'HMAC-SHA1'  
/// @param[in]  $url               URL to make request to  
/// @param[in]  $params            Array of key=>val for params. Don't  
///                                urlencode ahead of time, we'll do that here.  
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
function _make_signed_request( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $token_secret, $signature_method, $url, $params = array() ) {  

  // Only support GET in this function  
  $method = 'GET';  

  $signature_method = strtoupper( $signature_method );  
  if( $signature_method != 'PLAINTEXT' && $signature_method != 'HMAC-SHA1' ) {  
    print "Invalid signature method: ${signature_method}\n";  
    return false;  
  }  

  $oauth_nonce = rand( 0, 999999 );  
  $oauth_timestamp = time();  
  $oauth_version = '1.0';  

  $params['oauth_consumer_key'] = $consumer_key;  
  $params['oauth_nonce'] = $oauth_nonce;  
  $params['oauth_signature_method'] = $signature_method;  
  $params['oauth_timestamp'] = $oauth_timestamp;  
  $params['oauth_version'] = $oauth_version;  

  if( $token ) {  
    $params['oauth_token'] = $token;  
  }  
  if( ! $token_secret ) {  
    $token_secret = '';  
  }  

  // Params need to be sorted by key  
  ksort( $params, SORT_STRING );  

  // Urlencode params and generate param string  
  $param_list = array();  
  foreach( $params as $key => $value ) {  
    $param_list[] = urlencode( $key ) . '=' . urlencode( $value );  
  }  
  $param_string = join( '&', $param_list );  

  // Generate base string (needed for SHA1)  
  $base_string = urlencode( $method ) . '&' . urlencode( $url ) . '&' .   
    urlencode( $param_string );  

  // Generate secret  
  $secret = urlencode( $consumer_secret ) . '&' . urlencode( $token_secret );  
  if( $signature_method == 'PLAINTEXT' ) {  
    $signature = $secret;  
  } else if( $signature_method == 'HMAC-SHA1' ) {  
    $signature = base64_encode( hash_hmac( 'sha1', $base_string, $secret, true ) );  
  }  

  // Append signature  
  $param_string .= '&oauth_signature=' . urlencode( $signature );  
  $final_url = $url . '?' . $param_string;  

  // Make curl call  
  $ch = curl_init();  
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $final_url );  
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1 );  
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );  
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0 );  
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );  
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );  

  $timeout = 2; // seconds  
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );  
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );  

  $contents = curl_exec($ch);  
  $ret_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );  
  $errno = curl_errno($ch);  
  $error_str = curl_error($ch);  

  if( $errno || $error_str ) {  
    //print "Error: ${error_str} (${errno})\n";  
  }  

  //print "Response code: ${ret_code}\n";  
  //print "Contents:\n${contents}\n\n";  

  curl_close($ch);  

  $data = array(  
    'return_code' => $ret_code,  
    'contents'    => $contents,  
    'error_str'   => $error_str,  
    'errno'       => $errno   
  );  

  return $data;  
}  

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
//  FUNCTION oauth_response_to_array  
/// @brief Break up the oauth response data into an associate array  
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
function oauth_response_to_array( $response ) {  
  $data = array();  
  foreach( explode( '&', $response ) as $param ) {  
    $parts = explode( '=', $param );  
    if( count( $parts ) == 2 ) {  
      $data[urldecode($parts[0])] = urldecode($parts[1]);  
    }  
  }  
  return $data;  
}  

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
//  FUNCTION get_request_token  
/// @brief Get a request token for a given application.  
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
function get_request_token( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret ) {  

  $url = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token';  
  $signature_method = 'plaintext';  

  $token = NULL;  
  $token_secret = NULL;  

  // Add in the lang pref and callback  
  $xoauth_lang_pref = 'en-us';  
  $oauth_callback = 'oob';  // Set OOB for ease of use -- could be a URL  

  $params = array( 'xoauth_lang_pref' => $xoauth_lang_pref,  
                   'oauth_callback'   => $oauth_callback );  

  // Make the signed request without any token  
  $response_data = _make_signed_request( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $token_secret, $signature_method, $url, $params );  

  if( $response_data && $response_data['return_code'] == 200 ) {  

    $contents = $response_data['contents'];  
    $data = oauth_response_to_array( $contents );  

    //print_r( $data );  

    return $data;  
  }  

  return false;  
}  

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
//  FUNCTION get_access_token  
/// @brief Get an access token for a certain user and a certain application,  
///        based on the request token and verifier  
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
function get_access_token( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $request_token, $request_token_secret, $verifier ) {  

  $url = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token';  
  $signature_method = 'plaintext';  

  // Add in the oauth verifier  
  $params = array( 'oauth_verifier' => $verifier );  

  // Make the signed request using the request_token data  
  $response_data = _make_signed_request( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $request_token, $request_token_secret, $signature_method, $url, $params );  

  if( $response_data && $response_data['return_code'] == 200 ) {  

    $contents = $response_data['contents'];  
    $data = oauth_response_to_array( $contents );  

    //print_r( $data );  

    return $data;  
  }  

  return false;  
}  


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
//  FUNCTION make_request  
/// @brief Make an actual request to the fantasy API.  
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
function make_request( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret, $url ) {  

  $signature_method = 'hmac-sha1';  

  // Make the signed request to fantasy API  
  $response_data = _make_signed_request( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret, $signature_method, $url );  

  return $response_data;  
}  


// **** MAIN PROGRAM STARTS HERE ****  

$consumer_key = $consumer_data['test']['key'];  
$consumer_secret = $consumer_data['test']['secret'];  

// 1. Get Request Token  
$request_token_data = get_request_token( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret );  

if( ! $request_token_data ) {  
  print "Could not retrieve request token data\n";  
  exit;  
}  

$request_token = $request_token_data['oauth_token'];  
$request_token_secret = $request_token_data['oauth_token_secret'];  
$auth_url = $request_token_data['xoauth_request_auth_url'];  

// 2. Direct user to Yahoo! for authorization (retrieve verifier)  
print "Hey! Go to this URL and tell us the verifier you get at the end.\n";  
print ' ' . $auth_url . "\n\n";  

print "Type the verifier and hit enter...\n";  
$verifier = fgets( STDIN );  

print "Here's the verifier you gave us: ${verifier}\n";  

// 3. Get Access Token  
$access_token_data =  
  get_access_token( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $request_token, $request_token_secret, $verifier );  

if( ! $access_token_data ) {  
  print "Could not get access token\n";  
  exit;  
}  

$access_token = $access_token_data['oauth_token'];  
$access_token_secret = $access_token_data['oauth_token_secret'];  

// 4. Make request using Access Token  
$base_url = 'http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/';  
if( isset( $argv[1] ) ) {  
  $request_uri = $argv[1];  
} else {  
  $request_uri = 'fantasy/v2/game/nfl';  
}  
$request_url = $base_url . $request_uri;  

print "Making request for ${request_url}...\n";  

$request_data = make_request( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret, $request_url );  

if( ! $request_data ) {  
  print "Request failed\n";    
}  

$return_code = $request_data['return_code'];  
$contents = $request_data['contents'];  

print "Return code: ${return_code}\n";  
print "Contents:\n${contents}\n\n";  

print "Successful\n";  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code provided by Yahoo wasn't meant to be run as a web page, given this line:

```
$verifier = fgets( STDIN );
```

Instead it should be run in the console so that it can take advantage of `STDIN` and properly wait for user input.

But that doesn't really answer your question. If you want something that the user can enter -- at least as a quick test to prove that your code works -- [use a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277633/how-to-take-user-input-like-prompt-but-in-php) to grab user input, like below:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['value'];
?>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="value">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I'm not too familiar with PHP, but the next step would be to wrap this script into several functions, then execute the second half of the script once you have `$verifier` defined by the user via a form.